# How do I add a folder of files to a ListControl in JavaFx based on users selection?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to add a button that allows the user to select a folder of wav files which are then added to a ListControl where they can be selected for playback. I originally created a String variable which contained path to folder but would like now to allow the user choose a folder which is then loaded into ListControl. At the moment when user chooses folder the files do not add to ListControl. Here is what I have so far. Any tips or hints would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Molly2b extends Application {

private List<File> list = new ArrayList<File>();


private void init(final Stage primaryStage) { 
    Group root = new Group();
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));     
HBox hBox2 = new HBox();
    hBox2.setSpacing(20);
    hBox2.setTranslateY(30);                        
hBox2.getChildren().add(createChart());
final DirectoryChooser fileChooser = new DirectoryChooser();

final Button chooseDirButton = new Button("Choose Directory");
    chooseDirButton.setOnAction(
        new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
             public void handle(final ActionEvent e) {
         final DirectoryChooser dirChooser = new DirectoryChooser();

                 final File selectedDirectory = dirChooser.showDialog(primaryStage);
                 if (selectedDirectory != null) {  
                    selectedDirectory.getAbsolutePath();
                    addFilesFromDir(selectedDirectory);
                }
            }
        });



    VBox vBox = new VBox(50);
    vBox.getChildren().addAll(hBox2);



    final ObservableList<File> listObserv = FXCollections.<File>observableList(list);   
    ListView<File> listView = new ListView<File>(listObserv);
                         listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
        new ChangeListener<File>() {
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends File> ov, 
            File old_val, File new_val) {
            playAudio(new_val);                                             
        }
    });

    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
               bp.setLeft(listView);
           bp.setRight(vBox);
        bp.setTop(chooseDirButton);
    root.getChildren().add(bp);       
}

public void addFilesFromDir(File dir){

     if (dir.isDirectory()){ 
        File[] loopsList = dir.listFiles();
        for (File f:loopsList){
            String s = f.getName();             
            if (s.endsWith(".wav")){
                list.add(f);                    
            }               
        }           
    }
}


public void playAudio(File file){   
        try{
            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);            
         AudioFormat audioFormat = ais.getFormat();       
      DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class,audioFormat);                 
                       Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);                                                 
                             clip.open(ais);                                                             
                             clip.setLoopPoints(0,-1);                           
                             clip.loop(0);                          
        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex){
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ef){
        } catch (IOException e){
        }           
    }

@Override 
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    init(primaryStage);
    primaryStage.show();                
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Application.launch(args);       
}
}
```

Comment: Is `list.add(f);` ever executed? What exactly do you mean by `the files do not add to ListControl`? An error occurs or what?

Comment: No list.add(f); is not executed so I created an instance field for selectedDirectory instead and now its executed but the files still dont show up in the list view but they are added to the List now at least. What I mean is nothing happens. no errors it runs fine but when I choose the folder of files I want to add, the DirectoryChooser window closes but the .wav files from that folder are not added to the ListView.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like FileChooser or DirectoryChooser?

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/file-chooser.htm

Seems you have changed the question.

```
public class Molly2b extends Application {

private URI path;
private FileChooser fileChooser;// = new FileChooser();
private ObservableList<File> listype;// 
private ListView<String> listView;
private ListCell<String> listCell;

private void init(final Stage primaryStage) {

    Group root = new Group();
    HBox hBox2 = new HBox();
    hBox2.setSpacing(20);
    hBox2.setTranslateY(30);
    listView = new ListView<>();
    listCell = new ListCell<>();

    final Button chooseDirButton = new Button("Choose Directory");
    //listView.setCellFactory(TextFieldListCell.forListView());
    chooseDirButton.setOnAction(
            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(final ActionEvent e) {
                    fileChooser = new FileChooser();
                    listype = FXCollections.observableList();
                    fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(primaryStage)
                    if (listype != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < listype.size(); i++) {
                            path = listype.get(i).toURI();
                            String filename = listype.get(i).getName();
                            listCell.setItem(filename);
                            final ObservableList olist = FXCollections   
                                                          .observableArrayList();
                            olist.addListener(new InvalidationListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void invalidated(Observable o) {
                                    listView.getItems();
                                }
                            });
                            olist.addListener(new ListChangeListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change 
                                                                          change) {
                                    change.getList();
                                    listView.setItems(olist);
                                }
                            });
                            olist.setAll(listView.getItems());
                            olist.add(filename);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    VBox vBox = new VBox(50);
    vBox.getChildren().addAll(hBox2);
    //listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    listView.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(
                                             new ChangeListener<Number>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, 
                                               Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            ov.getValue();
            if(newValue.intValue == 0) {
                listView.getItems().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
                    @Override
                     public void invalidated(Observable o) {
                         listCell.getIndex();
                     }
                });
                path = listype.get(newValue.intValue()).toURI();
            }
            try {
                String newpath = path.toString();
                playAudio(newpath);
            } catch (IOException | 
                    LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {

            }
        }
    });

    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
    bp.setLeft(listView);
    bp.setRight(vBox);
    bp.setTop(chooseDirButton);
    root.getChildren().add(bp);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
}

public void playAudio(String path) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, 
                                           IOException, LineUnavailableException {
    Media media = new Media(path);
    final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
    player.play();
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    init(primaryStage);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}
}
```

Works as it should. Only thing that could need changing is that it can play 2 songs at the same time.

Comment: I decided not to use the MediaPlayer as I only want to play back short sounds like drum loops and I eventually want to add Frequency analysis but the Frequency analyzer that comes with JavaFx (though very easy to implement) is read only.

Comment: I got this to run but it does not add files to ListView plus I want to choose a folder of files and not individual files as in DirectoryChooser.

Comment: It adds a directory as in you can select multiple files in a directory while holding the Ctrl-key down. It was working like that for me. I don't know how to add an entire directory just by selecting it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you never add the files to the `ListView` but you add them only to the `List`.
You have to call `listView.getItems().add(f);` if you want them added to the `ListView`.